# Populating data from MySQL Database to DropDown in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, drop-down-menu

I have data in two different lists from the database, which is fetched using a POST request. I want to pop this data into two different `DropdownButton`. The data is fetched when the Screen opens. I've called the method in `initstate()` of the specific screen. 
Here is how I'm fetching data and creating lists:

```
void fetchData() {
  AppUtils.getStringFromPref("teacher_id").then(
    (teacher_id) async {
      final data = await http
          .post(AppUtils.teacherHomeLink, body: {"teacher_id": teacher_id});
      var responseBody = data.body;
      print(responseBody);
      final parsed = json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

      List<TeacherHomeData> parentSigninList = parsed
          .map<TeacherHomeData>((json) => TeacherHomeData.fromJson(json))
          .toList();

      for (int i = 0; i < parentSigninList.length; i++) {
        courseNameList.add(parentSigninList[i].course_name);
        batchNameList.add(parentSigninList[i].batch_name);
      }
    },
  );
}
```

Here's how the DropDownButton is being create:

```
DropdownButton(
  value: courseName,
  items: courseNameList.map((location) {
    return DropdownMenuItem(
      child: new Text(location),
      value: location,
    );
  }).toList(),
  onChanged: (newValue) {
    setState(() {
      courseName = newValue;
    });
  },
),
```

**Problem**
When the screen loads, it instantly creates an empty DropDownButton as the lists are initially empty. I want the DropDownButton to wait until the List is fetched successfully from the database. I'm getting the right way to do it, being a beginner in Flutter.

Comment: May I ask what I did wrong in this answer due to which it is being Downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is using Future function and FutureBuilder to fetch your async data and use it inside build method for widgets. Transform your function to `Future`;

```
Future<List> fetchData() async {
  var teacher_id = await AppUtils.getStringFromPref("teacher_id");
  final data = await http
      .post(AppUtils.teacherHomeLink, body: {"teacher_id": teacher_id});
  var responseBody = data.body;
  print(responseBody);
  final parsed = json.decode(data.body).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();

  List<TeacherHomeData> parentSigninList = parsed
      .map<TeacherHomeData>((json) => TeacherHomeData.fromJson(json))
      .toList();

  for (int i = 0; i < parentSigninList.length; i++) {
    courseNameList.add(parentSigninList[i].course_name);
    batchNameList.add(parentSigninList[i].batch_name);
  }
  return courseNameList;
}
```

and use FutureBuilder to build your widget after getting data from the server;

```
FutureBuilder<List>(
  future: fetchData(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return DropdownButton(
        value: courseName,
        items: snapshot.data.map((location) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            child: new Text(location),
            value: location,
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (newValue) {
          setState(() {
            courseName = newValue;
          });
        },
      );
    }
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
),
```

Comment: can I add multiple DropDownButton in the single FutureBuilder ?

Comment: Yes you can, actually you can do anything you want after your data returned from `Future`

Comment: Those codes refused to work until I add <String> on return DropsownMenuItem to look like this `return DropdownMenuItem<String>(` the remaining codes for me they was fine. Great thanks.